# Why my first use of the SPARKLINE function gives me an error?

Tags: google-sheets

My function:

```
=SPARKLINE({int(B4)-int($B$2),int(C4)-int(B4)},{"charttype","bar";"color1","white";"color2","green";"max",int($C$2)-int($B$2)})
```

I cannot find why I have that error in French:

> Erreur
>
> Erreur d'analyse de formule.

Comment: you are using French spreadsheet which has different syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you are French :) try it like this:

```
=SPARKLINE({int(B4)-int($B$2)\int(C4)-int(B4)};
 {"charttype"\"bar";"color1"\"white";"color2"\"green";"max"\int($C$2)-int($B$2)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, it works! But why backslashes instead of commas in French?

Comment: there are 2 syntaxes EU and US. EU syntax is with backslashes and semicolons while US is with semicolons and comas